# Finding errors in a code snippet

Tags: c++, debugging

I am asked to find the errors in the following code. There are apparently 5 errors, I have found three of them so far, here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
class Base{
public:
    Base(int data) : _data(data){}
    virtual void printData(){
        std::cout << "Base " << _data << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int _data;
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:
    Derived(derivdata) : Base(derivdata){}
    void printData(){
        std::cout << "Derived " << _data << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    Derived *var = new Derived(5);
    var->printData();
    Base* basevar = static_cast<Base>(*var);
    basevar->printData();
}
```

1. The class `Derived` does not end with a semi colon.
2. The argument of `Derived` constructor is not declared with a type
3. The data member of `Base` is pivate so cannot be accessed in `Derived` as is being attempted.

I am struggling to find the others, I suspect it is to do with the casting in `main()` but I don't yet know much about casting. I would appreciate any help in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Try compiling it - the compiler will always find your syntax errors for you. And yes, there is an issue (or two, depending on how you count), with the `static_cast` line.

Comment: Start by compiling the code, with lots of enabled warnings.

Comment: No virtual destructor in the base class. No `delete` to release `var`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Base* basevar = static_cast<Base>(*var);
```

This should be

```
Base* basevar = static_cast<Base*>(var);
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem, was a big help. Anyone know why my question was down voted? Seems an innocent enough question.